# GET DateTime from String

Tags: java, datetime

I am developing a java sample in which date is in string like - **2016-07-19T16:54:03.000+05:30**.
I want to convert it to DateTime object.How can I do it in java?
I have tried this code -

```
DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS+Z").parseDateTime("2016-07-19T16:54:03.000+05:30")
```

It give **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2016-07-19T16:54:03.000+05:30" is malformed at "05:30"** exception.

Comment: And what you have tried so far ?

Comment: google "java string to date"? :D

Comment: @shash678 gives exception - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern component: X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use *ZZ* instead of just Z for the timezone information.

i.e.

```
DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ").parseDateTime("2016-07-19T16:54:03.000+05:30")
```

Taken from the [Javadoc](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html):

> The count of pattern letters determine the format.
>
> Zone: 'Z' outputs offset without a colon, **'ZZ' outputs the offset with a colon**, 'ZZZ' or more outputs the zone id.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2016-07-19T16:54:03.000+05:30" is malformed at "05:30" exception

Comment: @paritaporwal, Sorry there was a typo in the pattern the "+" Symbol shouldn't be there. The line should be DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ").parseDateTime("2016-07-19T16:54:03.000+05:30"). Have edit the answer to reflect this change.

Comment: Thanks a lot...it works......

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");
      Date parsed = format.parse("2016-07-19T16:54:03.000+05:30");
      System.out.println(parsed);
    } catch (ParseException e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Tue Jul 19 11:54:03 UTC 2016
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/FnZW/1)

Comment: It changes my time from 16:54:03 to 11:54:03 UTC. which I dont want. I want time as it is.

Comment: then you need to format it with the timezone and whatever you want, I guess that was just an example how to parse it, not to format it for your output. since you didn't say what you ant to to with the date.

Answer (score 0):

You can try **java.text.DateFormat**

```
String DEFAULT_DATE_PARSE_PATTERN="dd.MM.yyyy";
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(DEFAULT_DATE_PARSE_PATTERN);
Date result = format.parse(your_value);
```

Comment: It only parse date like - Tue Jul 19 00:00:00 IST 2016.    I also want to parse time.....